# Connect to AWS with PHP client using SSH2

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, public-key, pem

I am trying to connect to mysql DB on AWS with PHP client.
The connection has 2 phases:
1 - connect to SSH port 22 using public/private key auth
2 - connect to mysql server on port 3306

I am having problem with the first phase. I have pem file and I have the following code:

```
<?php
include('SSH2.php');
include('RSA.php');

$key = new Crypt_RSA();
$key->loadKey(file_get_contents('path to pem file'));

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('server IP');
if (!$ssh->login('root', $key)) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Anyone has an example for end2end connection??

Answer (score 0):

I tested your script and it seems to work properly for me.

Kindly verify a few things to see why the ssh connection is not working,

1. Check that you are using the correct ssh private key [pem file] and that the permission on that file is readonly [ chown 0400 pemfile]
2. Check that the security group for the ec2 server allows port 22 to the IP address that the PHP is running on.
3. Check that you are using the correct Server IP, username. Generally speaking most of the EC2 server AMI are built with remote root login disabled, you will need to use the right username like on Amazon AMI you need to use ec2-user and on ubuntu amiit is ubuntu

Also please check on https://blog.rjmetrics.com/2009/01/06/php-mysql-and-ssh-tunneling-port-forwarding/ which gives in depth on what you are achieving